# How can I set the value of an <input> tag in JSP/Servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have some JSP code that looks like this:

```
    <form method=GET action="ControllerTwo">
      <p>How much money will you be the monthly payment?<br>
        <input type=text name=loan size=10 id=loan>
      </p>
    </form>
```

I need to set the value of the text box in the  tag to a predetermined value when another button elsewhere on the page is pressed. Here is a snippet of code from where that button is located:

```
    <form action="ControllerTwo" method="GET">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <input type=submit value="Principal:" name="principal">
          <input type=submit value="Delete" name="principalDel">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

When the principal button is pressed the value stored in a variable needs to get placed and displayed to the user as a submittable value in the  box text field.

Here is the code for the principal button when it is pressed:

```
//////////////////////////////
// Principal button was pressed.//
//////////////////////////////
if(request.getParameter("principal") != null) {
    System.out.println("Principal button was pressed...");
    
    // Wipe the htmlResponse clean.
    htmlResponse = "";
    
    // Build HTML code
    htmlResponse += "<html>\n"
            + "<head>\r\n"
            + "  <title>Mortgage Calculator</title>\r\n"
            + "  <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\r\n"
            + "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\r\n"
            + "  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\r\n"
            + "  <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css\">\r\n"
            + "  <script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>\r\n"
            + "  <script src=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js\"></script>\r\n"
            + "  <script src=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js\"></script>\r\n"
            + "  <link rel=\"preconnect\" href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com\">\r\n"
            + "  <link rel=\"preconnect\" href=\"https://fonts.gstatic.com\" crossorigin>\r\n"
            + "  <!-- Custom CSS -->\r\n"
            + "  <link href=\"style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">\r\n"
            + "</head>\r\n"
            + "<body>\r\n"
            + "<!-- Custom JS -->\r\n"
            + "<!-- <script src=\"script.js\"></script> -->\r\n"
            + "<div class=\"container row\">\r\n"
            + "  <div class=\"smp text-left col\">\r\n"
            + " <form method=GET action=\"ControllerTwo\">\r\n"
            + "   <p>How much money will you be borrowing?<br>\r\n"
            + "     <input type=text name=loan size=10 id=loan>\r\n"
            + "     <span class=\"smp-err\" id=\"loanError\"></span>\r\n"
            + "   </p>\r\n"
            + "   <p>What will be the monthly payment?<br>\r\n"
            + "     <input type=text name=payment size=5 id=payment>\r\n"
            + "     <span class=\"smp-err\" id=\"paymentError\"></span>\r\n"
            + "      </p>\r\n"
            + "   <p>What will be the interest rate?<br>\r\n"
            + "     <input type=text name=rate size=5 id=interest>\r\n"
            + "     <span class=\"smp-err\" id=\"ratesErr\"></span>\r\n"
            + "   </p>\r\n"
            + "   <input type=submit value=Submit name=sub>\r\n"
            + yearsAndMonths + "\n"
            + interestPaid + "\n"
            + " </form>\r\n"
            + " <form action=\"ControllerTwo\" method=\"GET\">\r\n"
            + "   <input type=submit value=Reset name=res>\r\n"
            + " </form>\r\n"
            + " <small>Instructions: Enter numbers and decimal points. No commas or other characters.</small>\r\n"
            + "  </div>\r\n"
            + "  <div class=\"smp text-left col\"> \r\n"
            + "   <h5 class=\"\">Logs:</h5>\r\n"
            + "   <form action=\"ControllerTwo\" method=\"GET\">\r\n"
            + "     <div class=\"col\">\r\n"
            + "     <div class=\"row\">\r\n"
            + "       <input type=submit value=\"Principal:\" name=principal>\r\n"
            + "       <p>$"+loanPTwo +"</p>"
            + "       <input type=submit value=\"Delete\" name=principalDel>\r\n"
            + "     </div>\r\n"
            + "     <div class=\"row\">\r\n"
            + "       <input type=button value=\"Monthly Payment:\" id=fieldTwo>\r\n"
            + "       <p>$"+paymentTwo +"</p>"
            + "       <input class=\"\" type=button value=\"Delete\" id=fieldTwo>"
            + "     </div>\r\n"
            + "     <div class=\"row\">\r\n"
            + "       <input type=button value=\"Interest:\" id=fieldThree>\r\n"
            + "       <p>$"+interestWhole +"</p>"
            + "       <input class=\"\" type=button value=\"Delete\" id=fieldThree>"
            + "     </div>\r\n"
            + "     <div class=\"row\">\r\n"
            + "       <p id=p4>Time Until Paid: "+ years + " years and " + months + " months" +"</p>\r\n"
            + "       <input type=button value=\"Delete\" id=fieldFour>\r\n"
            + "     </div>\r\n"
            + "     <div class=\"row\">\r\n"
            + "       <p id=p5>Total Interest: $" + interestTotalFormat +"</p>\r\n"
            + "       <input type=button value=\"Delete\" id=fieldFive>\r\n"
            + "     </div>\r\n"
            + "     <div>\r\n"
            + "       <input type=button value=\"Clear\" id=fieldSix>\r\n"
            + "     </div>\r\n"
            + "     </div>\r\n"
            +"    </form>\r\n"
            + "  </div>\r\n"
            + "</div>\r\n"
            + "</body>\n"
            + "</html>";
    
    // return response
    writer.println(htmlResponse);
    
    session.setAttribute("loan", loanPTwo);
    request.setAttribute("loan", loanPTwo);
}
```

How can I set this value so it displays the desired result?

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong. First of all, all the attribute values in your html code must be covered in quotes, e.g. <form method="GET" action="ControllerTwo">. Second, if the value, you want to set is already known on page load, you usually use Javascript (I prefer jquery) to set the value, so no page reload is required. I would also recommend to use an MVC framework, like Spring mvc to avoid return the whole page with all its overhead.

Comment: @TheFrozenOne This is an assignment for a class I am taking in which the teacher only wants us to use JSP and servlets.

Comment: Ok, so I think you just have to add the value attribute in your <input> tag, like this:
`<input type=text name=loan size=10 value=\"<<the value you want to set>>\" id=loan>\r\n"`
in your reponse, of course with all values in quotes. 
See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) article about html input elements